# Generating Random Matrix With Pairwise Distinct Rows and Columns

Tags: algorithm, math, random

I need to randomly generate an NxN matrix of integers in the range 1 to K inclusive such that all rows and columns individually have the property that their elements are pairwise distinct.

For example for N=2 and K=3

This is ok:

```
1 2
2 1
```

This is not:

```
1 3
1 2
```

(Notice that if K < N this is impossible)

When K is sufficiently larger than N an efficient enough algorithm is just to generate a random matrix of 1..K integers, check that each row and each column is pairwise distinct, and if it isn't try again.

But what about the case where K is not much larger than N?

Comment: This is closely related to [latin squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latin-square) so some of the same algorithms will be applicable.

Comment: Do you mean "no row or column contains 2 or more copies of the same element"?  "Pairwise distinct rows and columns" to me suggests that the requirement is that there must not be any pair of columns, nor any pair of rows, that are equal to each other at every element -- but then your 2nd matrix doesn't violate this, since the list of all rows and columns is `{ (1,3), (1,2), (1,1), (3,2) }` and there are no duplicates here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The keyword in the statement is "individually". For each row r in rows, the elements of r are pairwise distinct.  Likewise for columns.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: Thanks.  It was the absence of the word "elements", plus the presence of the word "pairwise", that were tripping me up -- things that are pairwise distinct are also just plain distinct! :)  I would have said: "... such that for each row, the elements within that row are distinct, and likewise for columns."

Comment: @j_random_hacker: If you just say distinct it isn't clear in what enclosing set.  For example if each row has distinct elements, it could be taken to mean they are distinct across the entire matrix.  The two examples intentionally distinguish all three cases.

Comment: I'm splitting hairs, but (a) adding "pairwise" doesn't provide any extra information about which set is intended as the enclosing set, and (b) my suggested phrasing ("for each row, the elements within that row are distinct") makes it perfectly clear what the enclosing set is, don't you think?

Comment: Elements of a set A are pairwise distinct implies from each other, therefore the scope is set A.  Elements of a set A are distinct, could mean distinct from all elements in a previously mentioned set B that is a superset of A.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but a warning about an intuitive solution that does not work.
I am assuming that by "randomly generate" you mean *with uniform probability on all existing such matrices*.

For N=2 and K=3, here are the possible matrices, up to permutations of the set [1..K]:

```
1 2    1 2    1 2
2 1    2 3    3 1
```

(since we are ignoring permutations of the set [1..K], we can assume wlog that the first line is `1 2`).

Now, an intuitive (but incorrect) strategy would be to draw the matrix entries one by one, ensuring for each entry that it is distinct from the other entries on the same line or column.
To see why it's incorrect, consider that we have drawn this:

```
1 2
x .
```

and we are now drawing x. x can be 2 or 3, but if we gave each possibility the probability 1/2, then the matrix

```
1 2
3 1
```

would get probability 1/2 of being drawn at the end, while it should have only probability 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (textual) solution. I don't think it provides good randomness, but nevertherless it could be ok for your application.

Let's generate a matrix in the range [0;K-1] (you will do +1 for all elements if you want to) with the following algorithm:

- Generate the first line with any random method you want.
- Each number will be the first element of a random sequence calculated in such a manner that you are guarranteed to have no duplicate in subsequent rows, that is for any distinct column x and y, you will have x[i]!=y[i] for all i in [0;N-1].
- Compute each row for the previous one.

All the algorithm is based on the random generator with the property I mentioned. With a quick search, I found that the [Inversive congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_congruential_generator) meets this requirement. It seems to be easy to implement. It works if K is prime; if K is not prime, see on the same page 'Compound Inversive Generators'. Maybe it will be a little tricky to handle with perfect squares or cubic numbers (your problem sound like sudoku :-) ), but I think it is possible by creating compound generators with prime factors of K and different parametrization. For all generators, the first element of each column is the seed.

Whatever the value of K, the complexity is only depending on N and is O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

1. Deterministically generate a matrix having the desired property for rows and columns.  Provided K > N, this can easily be done by starting the ith row with i, and filling in the rest of the row with i+1, i+2, etc., wrapping back to 1 after K.  Other algorithms are possible.
2. Randomly permute columns, then randomly permute rows.

Let's show that permuting rows (i.e. picking up entire rows and assembling a new matrix from them in some order, with each row possibly in a different vertical position) leaves the desired properties intact for both rows and columns, assuming they were true before.  The same reasoning then holds for column permutations, and for any sequence of permutations of either kind.

1. Trivially, permuting rows cannot change the property that, within each row, no element appears more than once.
2. The effect of permuting rows on a particular column is to reorder the elements within that column.  This holds for any column, and since reordering elements cannot produce duplicate elements where there were none before, permuting rows cannot change the property that, within each column, no element appears more than once.

I'm not certain whether this algorithm is capable of generating all possible satisfying matrices, or if it does, whether it will generate all possible satisfying matrices with equal probability.  Another interesting question that I don't have an answer for is: How many rounds of row-permutation-then-column-permutation are needed?  More precisely, is any finite sequence of row-perm-then-column-perm rounds equivalent to a bounded number of (or in particular, one) row-perm-then-column-perm round?  If so then nothing is gained by further permutations after the first row and column permutations.  Perhaps someone with a stronger mathematics background can comment.  But it may be good enough in any case.

Comment: I think you're onto something.  You can use a Fisher-Yates shuffle on the rows, and then again on the columns, and it will give a uniformly random permutation of the original matrix.  However your original matrix isn't the only one possible (up to row and column permutation).  The set of NxN elements of {1,2,..,K} can have different numbers of repeats. {{1,2},{2,1}} vs {1,2}{2,3}} for example.

Comment: You're right about the original matrix not being the only one possible.  And it seems plausible to me that choosing a row permutation uniformly at random and then doing the same for columns might give some kind of uniformly random permutation of the entire matrix, but I'd need to see a proof to be 100% convinced.  (I say "some kind" because we're deliberately excluding permutations that would, say, swap just 2 cells.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It doesn't even give all permutations of the original matrix.  Oh well, back to the drawing board.

Comment: If you have a small counterexample I'd be interested to see it -- I've bumped into problems like this before too!

Comment: {{1,2},{3,4}} -> {{1,2},{4,3}}

Comment: Thanks. OTOH, this matrix could be reached by renaming elements (1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 3).  We need to be prepared to do this anyway if K > n.  Still, renaming isn't enough to address the first problem you mentioned -- getting from {{1,2},{2,1}} to {1,2}{2,3}} or vice versa.